Problems in Python
I'm applying a Proportional-Derivative controller to control my robot, but I don't understand why the robot's position doesn't reach the desired position. Can someone help me understand what the error might be?
I want to observe the desired position (q_des) relative to the real position (q)
The error is related to the norm between the desired position q_des at the final time and the position obtained by my robot. Essentially, I want to provide my robot's joint torques with a PD control law to calculate tau:
tau = Kp * (q_des - q) - Kd * dq,
where q_des is the desired joint position, q is the actual position, dq is the actual joint velocity, and Kp and Kd are gains that you need to set. Where the accuracy of the simulation is evaluated by varying the time step dt of the simulator:
q_next = q + dt * dq
dq_next = dq + dt * ddq
from adam.casadi.computations import KinDynComputations
from adam.geometry import utils
import numpy as np
import casadi as cs
#import icub_models
from math import sqrt

urdf_path =  "/Users/tommasoandina/Desktop/doosan-robot2-master/dsr_description2/urdf/h2515.blue.urdf" 
# The joint list
joints_name_list = ['joint1', 'joint2', 'joint3', 'joint4', 'joint5', 'joint6']
# Specify the root link
root_link = 'base'

kinDyn = KinDynComputations(urdf_path, joints_name_list, root_link)
num_dof = kinDyn.NDoF

H = cs.SX.sym('H', 4, 4)
# The joint values
s = cs.SX.sym('s', num_dof)
# The base velocity
v_b = cs.SX.sym('v_b', 6)
# The joints velocity
s_dot = cs.SX.sym('s_dot', num_dof)
# The base acceleration
v_b_dot = cs.SX.sym('v_b_dot', 6)
# The joints acceleration
s_ddot = cs.SX.sym('s_ddot', num_dof)

# initialize
mass_matrix_fun = kinDyn.mass_matrix_fun()
coriolis_term_fun = kinDyn.coriolis_term_fun()
gravity_term_fun = kinDyn.gravity_term_fun()
bias_force_fun = kinDyn.bias_force_fun()
Jacobian_fun = kinDyn.jacobian_fun("link6")

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, kp, kd, dt, q_des):
        self.q_previous = 0.0
        self.kp = kp
        self.kd = kd
        self.dt = dt
        self.q_des = q_des
        self.first_iter = True

    def control(self, q, dq):
        if self.first_iter:
            self.q_previous = q
            self.first_iter = False

        self.q_previous = q
        return self.kp * (self.q_des - q) - self.kd * dq


   
class Simulator:
    def __init__(self, q, dt, dq, ddq):
        self.q = q
        self.dt = dt
        self.dq = dq
        self.ddq = ddq

    def simulate_q(self, tau, h2):
        dq = self.simulate_dq(tau, h2)
        self.q += self.dt * dq
        return self.q
    
    def simulate_dq(self, tau, h2):
        self.ddq = cs.inv(M2) @ (tau - h2)
        self.dq += self.dt * self.ddq
        return self.dq
    
    def simulate_ddq(self, M2, tau, h2):
        self.ddq = cs.inv(M2) @ (tau - h2)
        return self.ddq


#Valori randomici
q_des = (np.random.rand(num_dof) - 0.5) * 5
xyz = (np.random.rand(3) - 0.5) * 5
rpy = (np.random.rand(3) - 0.5) * 5
H_b = utils.H_from_Pos_RPY(xyz, rpy)
v_b = (np.random.rand(6) - 0.5) * 5
s = (np.random.rand(len(joints_name_list)) - 0.5) * 5
s_dot = (np.random.rand(len(joints_name_list)) - 0.5) * 5





M = kinDyn.mass_matrix_fun()
M2 = cs.DM(M(H_b, s))
M2 = M2[:6, :6]

h = kinDyn.bias_force_fun()
h2 = cs.DM(h(H_b, s, v_b, s_dot))
h2 = h2[:6]


q_0 = np.zeros(num_dof)
#q_0 = cs.SX.sym('q_0', num_dof)
kp = 0.1 
kd = sqrt(kp)
dt = 1.0 / 16.0 * 1e-3
total_time = 2.0 * 1e-3

#dq = cs.SX.sym('dq', num_dof)
#ddq = cs.SX.sym('ddq', num_dof)

dq = np.zeros(num_dof)
ddq = np.zeros(num_dof)


N = int(total_time / dt)

ctrl = Controller(kp, kd, dt, q_des)
simu = Simulator(q_0, dt, dq, ddq)

for i in range(N):
    tau = ctrl.control(simu.q, simu.dq)
    simu.simulate_q(tau, h2)
    simu.simulate_ddq(M2, tau, h2)

q_des_np = cs.DM(q_des).full().flatten()
simu_q_np = cs.DM(simu.q).full().flatten()

# Calcola l'errore medio all'infinito tra i vettori NumPy
errore_medio_infinito = np.max(np.abs(q_des_np - simu_q_np))

print(q_des_np)
print(simu_q_np)

print("Errore medio all'infinito:", errore_medio_infinito)

